# DELETE FROM <subquery>

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

```
DELETE FROM (SELECT * FROM orders1 o,order_item1 i
WHERE i.order_id = o.order_id );
```

above query has not mentioned particular  to delete rows.Instead of  i have mentioned a sub query.
But this query executes without any error and deletes `order_item1` table rows.

How oracle server decide which table rows should be deleted?
why `orders1` table rows cannot be deleted?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your case, the subquery's table `orders1` has most certainly a primary key 
(`order_id` ) and the table `order_item1` has the corresponding foreign key `order_id`.

Thus, Oracle turns the table `order_item1` into a **key preserved table** and is able to delete from this table in the outer `delete` statement.

The concept of *key preserved tables* is further explained at [This tahiti documentation link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/views.htm#ADMIN11783).

If you want to find out what is deleted you can go like so

These are the tables that are joined in your subquery:

```
create table tq84_orders1 (
   id     number primary key,
   col_1  varchar2(10),
   col_2  date
);

create table tq84_order_item1 (
  order_id references tq84_orders1,
  col_3    varchar2(10),
  col_4    date
);
```

This view emulates the subquery:

```
create view tq84_orders_v as (
  select * 
  from
    tq84_orders1     o,
    tq84_order_item1 i
  where
    o.id = i.order_id
);
```

This query (on `user_updateable_columns`) now finds which columns actually get deleted (or can be deleted):

```
select
  table_name,
  column_name,
--updatable,
--insertable,
  deletable
from
  user_updatable_columns
where
  table_name = 'TQ84_ORDERS_V';
```

The result shows that in effect the three columns ORDER_ID, COL_3 and COL_4 can be deleted, all of which stem from TQ84_ORDER_ITEM1.

```
TABLE_NAME                     COLUMN_NAME                    DEL
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ---
TQ84_ORDERS_V                  ID                             NO
TQ84_ORDERS_V                  COL_1                          NO
TQ84_ORDERS_V                  COL_2                          NO
TQ84_ORDERS_V                  ORDER_ID                       YES
TQ84_ORDERS_V                  COL_3                          YES
TQ84_ORDERS_V                  COL_4                          YES
```

Comment: I thought it would trigger `ORA-01752: cannot delete from view without exactly one key-preserved table`.

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar: you'de get this error message if no primary key were defined.

Comment: Also mentioning,If both tables have Primary Key, the table specified first in `FROM` clause is getting deleted!

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar: I assume if modern explicit `JOIN`s where used instead of the outdated implicit joins, it would delete from the table specified in the `from` clause, not the one in the `join` clause, right?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yup that makes sense. One another example proving the concept of _Modern_ syntax!

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar: hmm, doesn't seem to be that way. The join order doesn't matter. Only the "usable" PK seems to matter: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae907/1

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I see , Let me do my homework on this as well!

Answer (score 2):

I think that if you want to Delete rows from `just ONE` table you can use this query:

```
DELETE FROM orders1 WHERE order_id in 
(SELECT o.order_id FROM orders1 o,order_item1 i
WHERE i.order_id = o.order_id );
```

But if you want to delete rows from both tables you can do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_TAB AS SELECT o.order_id FROM orders1 o,order_item1 i
WHERE i.order_id = o.order_id;

DELETE FROM order_item1 WHERE order_id in 
(SELECT TEMP_TAB.order_id FROM TEMP_TAB);

DELETE FROM orders1 WHERE order_id in 
(SELECT TEMP_TAB.order_id FROM TEMP_TAB);

DROP TABLE TEMP_TAB;
```

Answer (score 0):

in your Sub Query you gave like "i.order_id = o.order_id".you can try like this

DELETE FROM (SELECT * FROM orders1 o,order_item1 i
WHERE  o.order_id=i.order_id);

this will be correct

Comment: There is no difference between your query and the one that was used

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to an Oracle environment at the moment so I can't verify, but the following does work in SQL Server and will delete from the Orders table.  If you want to delete from Order_Item, reverse the tables.

```
DELETE o
FROM   Orders o
       JOIN Order_Item oi ON o.order_id = oi.order_id
WHERE  [filter condition]
```

Comment: No, that won't work. Oracle doesn't allow joins in the from clause of a `delete` statement. Btw: here is an Oracle environment: http://sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score -2):

This might help you

`DELETE FROM  orders1 o CROSS JOIN order_item1 i WHERE i.order_id = o.order_id`

Comment: That wont' work in Oracle because it does not allow joins in a `DELETE` statement. (and I'm **absolutely** sure you don't want to delete from the cartesian product of two tables - even though you then turn the `cross join` into an inner join using outdated implicit join syntax in the where)